# How do I display all Giphy API search result images?

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, object, giphy-api

My Giphy API call is successful but now I'm trying to get all of the images to display instead of just the first one.  I'm sure there is a loop needed in here but I'm not sure how/when to make that happen.  Please see below for my HTML & jQuery code.  Thanks in advance for your time!

HTML

```html
<h1>WEB 230 Final - Github Giphy API Search</h1>

    <div class="outerWrapper">
      <p>Please record your query in the input box, select a rating from the drop down menu, and press the search button to view results.</p>

        <form>
          <input type="text" id="userQuery" value="Input your query here.">
          <label>
            <p>Rating:</p>
            <select id="rating">
              <option value="" selected>all</option>
              <option value="y">y</option>
              <option value="g">g</option>
              <option value="pg">pg</option>
              <option value="pg-13">pg-13</option>
              <option value="r">r</option>
            </select>
          </label>
          <br>
          <br>
          <button type="submit" id="searchButton">Search</button>
          <br>
          <br>
          <input type="reset" id="resetButton" value="Reset">
        </form>

        <div>
          <img id="searchResults" src=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Allows page to load prior to running jQuery code.
      $( document ).ready(function(){

        // Ques function to run once searchButton is clicked.
        $('#searchButton').on('click', function(){

          // Start to construct URL that will actually be utilized in the funtion by making individual variables (some of which are dynamic) that define the search criteria.
          var api = 'http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=';

          // Assign variable for userQuery so it can be dynamically applied to the url.
          var userInput = $('#userQuery').val().trim();
            // Convert input for a sucessful API call.
            userInput = userInput.replace(/ /g, "+");

          // Set limit for maximum amount of search results displayed on one page.
          var limit = '&limit=24';
/*
          // Assign variable for userRating so it can be dynamically applied to the url.
          var rating = $('#rating').val().trim();
            // Convert input for a sucessful API call.
            rating = userRnput.replace(/ /g, "+");
*/
          // API public key.
          var key = '&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC';

          // Create new variable called queryURL which pieces together all of the above variables.
          var queryURL = api + userInput + key + limit /*+ rating */;

           // Part 2 - Use AJAX to call GIPHY API (note that the .done() function waits for the API to respond)
          $.ajax({url: queryURL, method: 'GET'}).done(function(response){

            // This is the API response data. It's a JSON object of 24 gifs
            console.log(response.data);

            // For simplicity, we will take the first gif (ie. at postion 0)
            var giphyURL = response.data[0].images.fixed_height.url;
            console.log(giphyURL)

            // Plug image into html.
            $('#searchResults').attr('src', giphyURL);

          });

          // Part 3 - Clear the Gif using the reset_button id (#)
          $('#resetButton').on('click', function(){
            // Grab the img using the id and change the src to empty to remove the image
            $('#searchResults').attr("src",'');
          })

          // If using a jQuery click listner on a Submit button, you need to return false to prevent the default page refresh
          return false;
        })
        
      });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

So for your javascript, remember that arrays have a method called .length. This will return a number equal to the number of elements in an array. So consider this array:

```
var arrayStr = ["elem1", "elem2", "elem3"];
```

If you run the following code:

```
var x = arrayStr.length;
```

Then x will be equal to 3. How do we use this in a loop?

```
for (var i = 0, i < arrayStr.length, i++) {
    console.log(arrayStr[i]);
}
```

Coolio! Now we know how to loop through an array. Consider the object returned by the giphy api. You clearly already know how to get to the url of the first gif. We would use a loop something like this:

```
for (var i = 0, i < response.data.length; i++) {
    var giphyURL = response.data[i].images.fixed_height.url;
    var newImg = $("<img>");
    newImg.attr("src", giphyURL);
    $("#searchResults").append(newImg);
}
```

Obviously you'll need to pretty the page up a bit but at least here you have a starting point. Hope it helps. ^_^